# Log changes to Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I have around 15 more or less complex models. Of those I would like to track the changes. What's the simplest way? After-save/-update triggers?

Performance is important but if there is a way with low complexity but decreasing performance, I'll do it.

By the way: I do not want to use stored procedures. (Though I might, if there is a really simple way to do so...)

Thanks, Philip

Answer (score 0):

There is [verstal_versions](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions), which seems to do what you want to do.

It adds versionning over all the models you specify. See, for example :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  versioned

  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Then you can use your model's versions like this :

```
>> u = User.create(:name => "Steve Richert")
=> #<User first_name: "Steve", last_name: "Richert">
>> u.version
=> 1
>> u.update_attribute(:name, "Stephen Richert")
=> true
>> u.name
=> "Stephen Richert"
>> u.version
=> 2
>> u.revert_to(10.seconds.ago)
=> 1
>> u.name
=> "Steve Richert"
```

Comment: Definitely interesting... Though I fear complexity that might affect performance and maintenance...

Comment: Well, I've seen vestal_versions in large-scale applications, it's quite fast and very usable.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at [Dirty objects](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) provided by ActiveRecord out of the box.  This gives you the ability to work with objects while they're in the process of being saved so that you can log the changes to a separate table.

Comment: Dirty objects exist in 2.x as well. See [this link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html). My understanding is they work pretty much the same as they do in AR 3+.